# How can I .trim() the display field of a Vaadin combobox?

Tags: java, combobox, vaadin, trim, vaadin7

In `Vaadin 7.x`, I have a `ComboBox` setup using a `JPAContainer`.  It's setup like:

```
mycombo.setItemCaptionPropertyId("name");
```

Works great.  However, the entity that is mapped to that combo uses a `CHAR(50)` column for the `name` and this cannot be changed.  Everything works fine, but it's annoying to see all of those spaces when I copy/paste, for example, from the combo to some other text input.

Naturally, I `.trim()` the combo value when I pass it in programmatically but I would like to always trim the display automatically.

Would I do this by creating a custom converter?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post some screenshots? It would better help understand

Comment: Not at the moment but I can later if really needed.  But basically, if the display value of the combo should be `"Apple"` but in the database, it comes back as `"Apple             "`.  I want it to show `"Apple"` even though that's not what was loaded from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Due to a lack of time I can't find anything better than the following:

```
public class MyVaadinUI extends UI {

@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = MyVaadinUI.class, widgetset = "com.gabrielruiu.vaadin.AppWidgetSet")
public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
}

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    layout.setMargin(true);
    setContent(layout);

    ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox("my combobox", Arrays.asList("  Killer croc  ", "        Joker", "Penguin      "));
    comboBox.setConverter(new Converter<Object, String>() {

        @Override
        public String convertToModel(Object value, Class<? extends String> targetType, Locale locale) throws ConversionException {
            if (value != null) {
                return value.toString();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Object convertToPresentation(String value, Class<?> targetType, Locale locale) throws ConversionException {
            if (value != null) {
                return value.trim();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<String> getModelType() {
            return String.class;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<Object> getPresentationType() {
            return Object.class;
        }
    });
    layout.addComponent(comboBox);
}

}
```

The problem is that, while testing it, the value in the combobox disappears after I select it. If you can find a solution then that's great but this is what I could scrounge up for the moment.